# Can't decode characters in opening CSV file

Tags: python, file, csv, decode

I have a problem that I absolutely have no idea why this is happening. I tried a million things but to no avail. It's just a simple OOP assignment, but I'm new at Python and I'm stuck.

I have this directory tree:

```
Assignment
|
|___project
    |
    |__src
       |   __init__.py
       |   book.py
       |   books.csv
       |   database.py
       |   main.py
       |
       |__.vscode
       |
       |__ __pycache__
```

So in database.py I want to open the books.csv file and include its contents in a list, like so:

```
class Database(object):

    db = []

    with open('books.csv', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        db = list(reader)
```

These are the contents of the csv file:

```
The Lord of the Rings,J. R. R. Tolkien,0395595118
The Alchemist (O Alquimista),Paulo Coelho,9780061122415
The Little Prince (Le Petit Prince),Antoine de Saint-Exupéry,0156012197
Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone,J. K. Rowling,9780747532743
The Master and Margarita (Мастер и Маргарита),Mikhail Bulgakov,0143108271
Alice's Adventures in Wonderland,Lewis Carroll,0744561248
The Hobbit,J. R. R. Tolkien,054792822X
And Then There Were None,Agatha Christie,0062073486
Dream of the Red Chamber (紅樓夢),Cao Xueqin,0146001761
```

I receive this error:

```
File "c:\Users\castr\Desktop\Assignment\project\src\database.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Database(object):
  File "c:\Users\castr\Desktop\Assignment\project\src\database.py", line 10, in Database
    db = list(reader)
  File "C:\Users\castr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 279: character maps to <undefined>
```

I'm pretty sure it's just a stupid thing I'm missing but I can't do it. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open. You need to specify encoding

Comment: Option `encoding="UTF-8"` should do. On Windows, Python's default encoding is Latin-1 (or maybe Windows-1252, which is roughly equivalent), at least in Western Europe. When opening a text file, you need to always check the encoding, or you will either get errors, or bad characters.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut the default encoding may depend on your version of Python, version of Windows, or both.  Best to be explicit, and best to know precisely the encoding of the file rather than guessing.

Comment: @MarkRansom Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but it's precisely what I was trying to say. Just a remark: often you have no other way but guess. Sadly, csv datasets (and more generally text files) are rarely accompanied by a documentation that tells precisely the encoding. And I have already seen a botched csv file using two different encodings for two different fields.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes, often CSV files are just a dumpster fire.  It's really unfortunate that UTF-8 wasn't invented earlier.